# Как ввести двумерный массив с клавиатуры? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как ввести двумерный массив с клавиатуры, не имея на вход ни количество строк, ни столбцов, завершая массив ключевым словом, к примеру, 'end'?

Comment: Рафаэль, в будущем рекомендую вам добавлять в вопрос ваши собственные попытки решения проблемы. По правилам сайта, вы не можете публиковать т.н. вопросы-домашние-задания.

Comment: "не имея на вход ни количество строк, ни столбцов"... можно обойтись без чего-то одного (зная общее к-во и к-во строк, вычислить к-во столбцов), но если нет ни того, ни другого... может быть только плоский, одномерный массив

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например так:

```
arr = []

while True:
    text = input()
    
    if text == 'end':
        break
        
    arr.append(list(map(int, text.split())))
```

по хорошему надо еще проверить, что список списков содержит одинаковое кол-во элементов в каждом элементе (чтобы уж был точный двумерный массив) или свести к минимуму кол-во таких элементов